# How do I auth on docker-entrypoint-init.d's script

Tags: javascript, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I want to create user on MongoDB with docker-compose.
I could create MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USER using docker-compose environment property.

and MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USER has permission that connecting to admin using password.

but, I couldn't run script which is to create new user to new db in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d and the docker-compose log is below.

```
mongodb    | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0-user.js
mongodb    | 2018-10-08T10:16:20.696+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:45976 #3 (1 connection now open)
mongodb    | 2018-10-08T10:16:20.697+0000 I NETWORK  [conn3] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:45976 conn3: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "3.6.8" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"", architecture: "x86_64", version: "Kernel 4.15.0-1022-azure" } }
mongodb    | 2018-10-08T10:16:20.699+0000 I ACCESS   [conn3] Unauthorized: not authorized on admin to execute command { usersInfo: 1.0, $db: "admin" }                                       
mongodb    | 2018-10-08T10:16:20.699+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: not authorized on admin to execute command { usersInfo: 1.0, $db: "admin" } :
mongodb    | _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
mongodb    | DB.prototype.getUsers@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1686:1                                                                                                                              
mongodb    | @/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0-user.js:17:20
mongodb    | failed to load: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0-user.js                                                                                                                           
mongodb    | 2018-10-08T10:16:20.700+0000 I NETWORK  [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:45976 (0 connections now open)
```

How do I auth to execute command on admin from docker-entrypoint-initdb.d's scripts?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to sof. Could you provide your docker-compose file, and script you use to create user?

Comment: Did you set env of MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE?

Comment: Thank you for your messaging.
I had solved this issue using MONGODB_USER instead for MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USER.